# Lock/disable/hide WordPress theme options until user has signed up for newsletter

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently working on a custom theme's 'theme options' panel for a client that plans to distribute the theme for free after I am finished.

The client would like the theme options panel hidden/locked until the user has signed up for a newsletter. I have never done this before and was wondering if anybody has come across a tutorial or can point me in the right direction.

I've tried 'Googling' this topic for the past hour, but I haven't found anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress questions are best asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

How about check user has been signed up or not before adding new menu for your theme options?

maybe look like this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'reg_my_theme_options' );

function reg_my_theme_options(){

    if(!is_user_signup_newsletter())
        return;

    add_menu_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme options', 'manage_options', 'theme-options', 'my_theme_options' ); 
}

function my_theme_options(){
    // here your theme options page
    echo "Admin Page Test"; 
}

function is_user_signup_newsletter(){
    // here your signup newsletter logic
    // maybe stored on options table
    $nlt_signup_status = get_option( 'signed_up_newsletter', 'no' );
    if($nlt_signup_status == 'yes'){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```